# why can't i change this div's innetHTML with ajax?

Tags: ajax

Just started today learning ajax and fell on the very first step, the worse thing is, i can't really find what's wrong with the code, can you guys spot it?

The div's inner html should change to the responseText inside the data.txt . The text inside this file is "Hey man" (cuz no one likes hello world)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hehe">Ha...here we are, this will be an ajax demonstration!</div>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','data.txt');
document.onreadystatechange= function () {
  if((this.readyState===4) && (this.status===200)) {
      document.getElementById('hehe').innerHTML = request.responseText ;
  }
};
request.send();
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `request.onreadystatechange` not `document.onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score 2):

You meant `request.onreadystatechange = function () ...`, not `document.onreadystatechange`.